# Could not read script 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ntpanchal/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle' as it does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I want to upload library project to jCenter and follow all steps from [this](http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-to-publish-android-library-on-bintrayjcenter/) blog

```
./gradlew clean build install bintrayUpload
```

When i execute above command from android studio terminal then it will give following error.

> Could not read script
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ntpanchal/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
>   as it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You use the wrong script. Use this instead:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numetriclabz/jcenter/master/installv.gradle
```

The one you tried using doesn't exist (open it in a browser; 404). The repo doesn't exist either.

Comment: First of all thanks Zoe for reply. i know https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ntpanchal/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle link not exist but all other library creator used their own github username in this link so i was change **numetriclabz** to **ntpanchal** like this.
 https://github.com/nuuneoi/FBLikeAndroid/blob/master/fb-like/build.gradle#L54

Comment: @NileshPanchal in order to do that, you actually have to add the script to a repo called `jcenter` on your account

Comment: How to add script to jCenter for use own name in library?